# Jasmine test in angular how to add metadata

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Lets say I have a test.

```
it('Should do something, () => {
    // Given
    // When
    // Then
});
```

How can I add metadata to this that they will be available in result.
Something like this:

```
[E2E]
[TeamXYZ]
[SomeOtherStuff]
it('Should do something, () => {
    // Given
    // When
    // Then
});
```

Comment: its not possible in jasmine, there is no decorators! looks like a feature you want to request on their github page!

Comment: @NarenMurali And isnt there any different syntax for metadata?